# `Tween vs Frame animation in Android? performance difference

Tags: android, performance, memory, animation

So we know about this two ways of implementing [animations on Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

I couldn't find any performance difference if there are any..

I am aware that frames will make apk file bigger (picture for each frame), and that with tween you need/can precisely to define animation, but which way of animating is from memory/cpu consumption side more efficient? Any clue?

Thanks